# LDAP Authentication with Apache Tomcat 7, JSF with Realm

Tags: xml, apache, jsf, tomcat, tomcat7

i am having troubles to authenticate users with LDAP, i have configured my server.xml and my web.xml, the thing is that the page always redirect to the error page but the log does not shows any message or error,  i have read about a SSL certificate which has to be imported to the JVM (I don't know how to do that, is it neccesary?)

Anybody knows what is the issue?

web.xml

```
   <security-constraint>
       <display-name>Security Constraint</display-name>
       <web-resource-collection>
       <web-resource-name>Protected Area</web-resource-name>
         <!-- Define the context-relative URL(s) to be protected -->
       <url-pattern>/admin/*</url-pattern>
        <!-- If you list http methods, only those methods are protected -->
       </web-resource-collection>
       <auth-constraint>
    <!-- Anyone with one of the listed roles may access this area -->
          <role-name>admin</role-name>
       </auth-constraint>
    </security-constraint>


   <login-config>
       <auth-method>FORM</auth-method>
       <realm-name>Form-Based Authentication Area</realm-name>
    <form-login-config>
       <form-login-page>/view/portal/login.jsp</form-login-page>
       <form-error-page>/authentication/login.xhtml</form-error-page>
    </form-login-config>
  </login-config>

  <!-- Security roles referenced by this web application -->
  <security-role>
       <role-name>admin</role-name>
   </security-role>
```

server.xml

```
   <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.JNDIRealm" debug="99"
                              connectionName="uid=......,ou=profile,dc=domain,dc=com"
                connectionPassword="password"
                connectionURL="ldap://domain"
                userPattern="uid={0},ou=people,dc=domain,dc=com"
                roleBase="ou=group,dc=domain,dc=com"
                roleName="cn"
                roleSearch="memberUid={1}"
        />
```